# Using goo.gl url shortener with oauth on command line

Tags: authentication, url-shortening

I am wondering if anybody came up with a command line tool that allow to shorten a url with goo.gl service via Oauth authentication.

I am aware of solutions like [this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6709/google-url-shortener) which allow shortening url with goo.gl **without** using Oauth authentication for stats of the url and such.

I had a quick look at [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) but it didn't seem to support goo.gl url shortener service.